# How to set a JField into a double value, instead of the default string type

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I am trying to change the type of Jtextfield into a double value as follows:

```
rangespaceField3.setText(bmi.getBMI());
```

The getBMI method returns a double value but gets the following error:

> JTextComponent is not applicable for the arguments (double)

Comment: You will have to process with the String only. Rather what you can do is convert that value int double by Double.parseDouble() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rangespaceField3.setText(String.valueOf(bmi.getBMI()));
```

[`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) will return a string representation of primitive data types.

Answer (score 2):

Try `rangespaceField3.setText(Double.toString(bmi.getBMI()));`

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented number fields based on JFormattedTextField.

JRealNumberField and JLocalizedRealNumberField are text fields for BigDecimal.

They also support a min and a max value.

Maybe you find them useful (the library is open source):

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JRealNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JDoubleField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JFloatField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedRealNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedDoubleField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedFloatField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JWholeNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JByteField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JIntegerField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLongField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JShortField.html

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/tutorial/swing/number/index.html

Homepage:

http://www.softsmithy.org

Download:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupid>org.softsmithy.lib</groupid>  
    <artifactid>lib-core</artifactid>  
    <version>0.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

Comment: +1 sorry as you can see here, to reinvent the wheel is way ..., rather than use proper JComponent, eeerrghtt

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to put the string representation of the double into the text field then you use the valueOf() method in the String class.

```
rangespaceField3.setText(String.valueOf(bmi.getBMI()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out....

// Concatinate double value with empty string, that will convert double to string

rangespaceField3.setText(bmi.getBMI()+"");

```
                OR
```

//Call toString() on double value returned from the method, that too will be converted to String

rangespaceField3.setText(bmi.getBMI().toString());